# How to tell CMake to use during compilation specific version of Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

There are two versions of Qt installed on my Ubuntu - 5.2 (default) and 5.4 (in /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64):

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(testproject)
find_package(Qt5Core HINTS /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64 REQUIRED)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main Qt5::Core)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>
int main()
{
  qDebug() << "runtime version: " << qVersion() << " compiled with: " << QT_VERSION_STR << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Running the program:

```
cmake . && make clean && make && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib ./main
```

Output:

```
runtime version:  5.4.0  compiled with:  5.2.1
```

How to tell inside CMake to use Qt 5.4 instead of default Qt 5.2? I've tried several options for `HINTS` in `find_package` but none of them looks to work.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look through the CMake files generated by an installation of Qt5, and no where in those files are hints being ingested from the caller. These CMake files all use relative paths once one of them is picked up.

That is, if you're looking for the core library, then all of the dependencies that version of the core library will be the correct version. So the goal is to get it to pick the right CMake module when you call `find_package`, and there are a couple of ways to do that using CMake level hints.

### Export `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

You can set the prefix path to the base directory your Qt is installed to. The base directory is the directory containing `lib/` and `bin/`. In your case, this might be something like this:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
```

and then from the same shell session run your cmake commands.

### Set `Qt5Core_DIR` in your `CMakeLists.txt`

This requires setting a variable that points to the right CMake root module you want your Qt to be found from:

```
set(Qt5Core_DIR /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
```

Of course, the issue with this is that if you wanted to find another module, you'd have to set the specific `Qt5<MODULE>_DIR` variable before your `find_package` call.

Comment: For me I have not had to do the set(Qt5Core_DIR ... ) albeit I'm on msvc. I just have to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as you did.

Comment: @iminyourbrain, are you saying that the second method did not work for you, or that you didn't need to use the second method because the first worked? I never claimed it was necessary to do both, either one should work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize these were two different ways for the same goal. The first one is the way I generally go.